# Logout from parse.com does not clear session token on Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am building an App that relies heavily on users in parse.com.
I have a problem when logging out and then logging in again, all requests get "invalid session exception".

If I kill the App and tries again, everything works ok (I don't need to re-log, it just works as soon as I restart the app).

All my parse queries are done via a Sync adapter and a sync service.

I tried stopping the service, clearing cookies cache and everything I could think of.
I'm not sure if it's an issue with parse.com or with the android's sync adapter / sync service.

Can anyone shed light on how to force Android (or parse) to flush the session token?

Login:

```
@Override
public void onLoginClicked(final String email, String password) {

    ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage(getString(R.string.logging_in));
    progress.show();

    try {
        ParseUser.logIn(email,password);
        ParseUser me = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (me != null) {
            DoUIParseSyncAdapter.updateInstallation();
            if (me.getString(DoUIParseSyncAdapter.PARTNER_ID) != null) {
                goToMainScreen();
            }
            else {
                showConnectToPartnerScreen(email);
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this,R.string.login_failed,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Logout:

```
 public static void logout(final Context context) {
    ParseUser.logOutInBackground(new LogOutCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            DbHelper helper = new DbHelper(context);
            helper.onUpgrade(helper.getWritableDatabase(), 0, 0);
            DoUISyncAdapter.removeSyncAccount(context);


            context.stopService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),DoUISyncService.class));

            CookieManager manager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                manager.removeAllCookies(new ValueCallback<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(Boolean aBoolean) {

                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                manager.removeAllCookie();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

SyncAdapter:

```
public class DoUISyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

private static final String LOG_TAG = DoUISyncAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

public static final int SYNC_INTERVAL = 60 * 180;
public static final int SYNC_FLEXTIME = SYNC_INTERVAL/3;

public DoUISyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
    super(context, autoInitialize);
}

@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle bundle, String s, ContentProviderClient contentProviderClient, SyncResult syncResult) {

    String table = bundle.getString("requestedTable");

    if (table == null) {
        DoUIParseSyncAdapter.getInstance().syncTasks(getContext());
        //DoUIParseSyncAdapter.getInstance().syncGeneralItems(getContext());
        DoUIParseSyncAdapter.getInstance().syncShoppingItems(getContext());
    }
    else {
        if (table.equals(DoUIContract.PATH_TASKS)) {
            DoUIParseSyncAdapter.getInstance().syncTasks(getContext());
        }
        else if (table.equals(DoUIContract.PATH_SHOPPING)) {
            DoUIParseSyncAdapter.getInstance().syncShoppingItems(getContext());
        }
    }
}

public static void initializeSyncAdapter(Context context) {
    getSyncAccount(context);
}

public static void syncImmediately(Context context,String table) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
    bundle.putString("requestedTable",table);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(getSyncAccount(context),
            context.getString(R.string.content_authority), bundle);
}

public static Account getSyncAccount(Context context) {
    // Get an instance of the Android account manager
    AccountManager accountManager =
            (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);

    // Create the account type and default account
    Account newAccount = new Account(
            context.getString(R.string.app_name), context.getString(R.string.sync_account_type));

    // If the password doesn't exist, the account doesn't exist
    if ( null == accountManager.getPassword(newAccount) ) {

    /*
     * Add the account and account type, no password or user data
     * If successful, return the Account object, otherwise report an error.
     */
        if (!accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, "", null)) {
            return null;
        }
        /*
         * If you don't set android:syncable="true" in
         * in your <provider> element in the manifest,
         * then call ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1)
         * here.
         */

    }
    return newAccount;
}

public static void configurePeriodicSync(Context context, int syncInterval, int flexTime) {
    Account account = getSyncAccount(context);
    String authority = context.getString(R.string.content_authority);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // we can enable inexact timers in our periodic sync
        SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder().
                syncPeriodic(syncInterval, flexTime).
                setSyncAdapter(account, authority).
                setExtras(new Bundle()).build();
        ContentResolver.requestSync(request);
    } else {
        ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account,
                authority, new Bundle(), syncInterval);
    }
}

public static void removeSyncAccount(Context context) {

    ContentResolver.cancelSync(getSyncAccount(context),context.getString(R.string.content_authority));
    ContentResolver.removePeriodicSync(getSyncAccount(context),context.getString(R.string.content_authority),new Bundle());

    AccountManager accountManager =
            (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
    for (int index = 0; index < accounts.length; index++) {
        if (accounts[index].type.intern() == "com.ymgeva.doui")
            accountManager.removeAccount(accounts[index], null, null);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSyncCanceled() {
    super.onSyncCanceled();
    getContext().stopService(new Intent(getContext(),DoUISyncService.class));
}

public static void onAccountCreated(Context context) {

    DoUISyncAdapter.configurePeriodicSync(context, SYNC_INTERVAL, SYNC_FLEXTIME);
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(getSyncAccount(context), context.getString(R.string.content_authority), true);
    syncImmediately(context,null);
}
```

}

Comment: Hey - I know this is a very old question, but I'm having the same exact problem on Android - did you ever figure out how to fix it?